# Images not loading in canvas

Tags: html, image, canvas

I am having trouble getting all my images to load for my canvas project at school. I can get the red dot to load and follow the mouse like its supposed to, but the rest does not want to work. Do I have a syntax error or am I missing a line of code? Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here is a link to the playcode:

https://playcode.io/599039/

Comment: What is not load? mouse.jpg?

Comment: The mouse jpg, there is a piece of cheese png and the brezier curve as well.

Comment: but in playcode is on local path i think can you upload that?

Comment: Look at what you are doing with `context.clearRect` you keep on erasing what you draw